# Cumulative standard deviation calculation

Tags: estimation, descriptive-statistics, biostatistics

I have a calculated daily survival probability, and associated SE. From this I can obtain the standard deviation. I have to report the cumulative survival over a specific period. So for example, for a 38 day period, where daily survival rate (DSR) = 0.97, and SD = 0.16, the probability of survival over the period is simply 0.97^38 = 0.314. Is there a way to calculate the cumulative SD as well? Is it appropriate to do so? Note too that in this example DSR is constant, but DSR and SD can, in some situations, vary over the period.

This may be pretty straight forward, but I can't seem to find a comprehensible answer. Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: What does the SD there measure? How is it related to SE? How was the SE computed?  I'm not sure that taking the product of the uncertain estimate of the expectation will leave you with the expectation of 38-day survival. You say DSR is constant - how do you know this?.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This is obviously not my strong point. The DSR is calculated from a model specifically constraining constant survival. In an AIC comparison, this was the best model, though there was uncertainty - this is for a gov't report where they just want avgs. though, so it is a best approximation for comparing yearly estimates. The SE was calculated internally via standard mark-recapture style survival estimation. SD was simply calculated as SE*sqrt(effective n). This is all standard procedure. I have to shoehorn reality into a fixed estimate of 38 day survival from the daily est.